# Is there a way to force all file transactions with a filesystem to be UTF8 or UTF16 compliant?

Tags: linux, filenames, utf-8

What I want is to specify that for a directory, every file creation/modification within said directory will be checked by the kernel and if the filename has unsupported characters the offending process will be given a "permission denied" error.

I was thinking about writing a fuse-driver that rejects non-compliant filenames. But that does not seem practical.

I am not looking for solutions that recommend things like a cronjob or inotify that clean up unwanted characters after-the fact.  I'm looking for something that is preemptively preventative.

Comment: What filesystem are you using? `mount` has some file system specific options that could (I said _could_, never tried it) help. Search `man mount` for `unicode` or `utf8`.

Comment: I'm using ext4. I read the manpage: nothing interesting. The classic unix way regarding filenames is not to care about them at all, as long as they don't contain / or the 0-byte. I have never heard of the feature I'm requesting, thus my question.

Comment: What does "unicode filename" even mean in this context? Do you want to ensure all filenames are valid UTF-8?

Comment: Yes. sorry I didn't say that.

Comment: On the other hand, it we would be nice, if the encoding could be specified on an per directory basis. Like utf16 for a collection of files named in chinese and utf8 in another directory for files mostly named  in european languages.

Comment: You're out of luck - the filesystem doesn't have a concept of "character set", filenames are simply byte sequences, with only / and \0 disallowed, as you say. You'd need to intercept all filename creation calls (linking, renaming, creating), either at the filesystem layer or by changing glibc (directly or monkey-patching via LD_PRELOAD - that one's easier to do and hard to enforce). There's no "intended" way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

ZFS has mechanisms for making datasets (and maybe pools) be UTF8 only, potentially with different normalization mechanisms.

Further reading:

http://www.mail-archive.com/zfs-discuss@opensolaris.org/msg28314.html

http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=zfs&manpath=FreeBSD+9.1-RELEASE